# Why does the C# compiler think I'm trying to use the sbyte overload when using nullable longs?

Tags: c#, overloading

The following code

```
long? long1 = 1;
long? long2 = 2;
Math.Min(long1.Value, long2);
```

will result in the following error message on both arguments:

- "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'long' to 'sbyte'"
- "Argument 2: cannot convert from 'long?' to 'sbyte'"

**I understand why this is an error, I know how to resolve the error.**

My question is why is the compiler trying to choose the `Math.Min(sbyte, sbyte)` overload in this case (even when the first argument is not a nullable)?

Comment: Interesting... To resolve this, you could add a cast to both values: `Math.Min((long)long1.Value, (long)long2);`

Comment: It probably can't find the right overload, so based on some ordering it chooses that one, giving you two errors. Probably choosing that overload because it comes first in the code of the library.

Comment: I know how to resolve it, I'm just wondering why it's acting like that

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich, that's what I thought to, but the ordering doesn't make sense, it's not the first one alphabetically or by order of declaration. So what's the ordering process here?

Comment: @SamArustamyan in the decompiled source it is the first one.

Comment: I just looked at the metadata and it wasn't the first one. Makes sense now, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can't find the right overload, so it defaults to the first one in Math.cs, which happens to be `public static sbyte Min(sbyte val1, sbyte val2)`